# Trees in a Stack

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, stack

My program is supposed to receive an equation (ex: x^4*(x+3)) and transform it into post order (or reverse polish notation), after that I need to create a tree that needs to be put in a stack. The tricky part is reading through the post order equation. In the example it should be:

x 4 ^ x 3 + *

So the rules about the tree making is:

If it's a binary operation ("+","-","^","/","*") it should take the first 2 elements of a stack, create a tree with the operation as a root, and the numbers as its sons, and push it into the stack.

If it's a unary operation ("&" which represents ln, "~" which represents the negative (~3)=(-3)), it shoudl take the first element of a stack, create a tree with the operation as root, and the number as its son, and push it inside the stack.

If it's a number or letter, it should create a node with no sons, and just push it into the stack.

My algorithm to detect if it's a letter, binary or unary operation through the string is:
(The Post order equation is already created, it was sent by my teacher so there's nothing to edit there)

```
String aux="";
for (int i=0; i < nuevaF.length();i++){
    char c = nuevaF.charAt(i);
    if (c!=' '){
        aux=aux+c;  
        System.out.println(aux);
    }
    if (c==' '){
        System.out.println("space");
        Transformar(stack,aux);
        aux="";
    }
 }
```

And then to create the Stack:

```
public static void Transformar(PilaArreglo stack, String ecuacion){

        if (ecuacion=="+"||ecuacion=="-"||ecuacion=="*"||ecuacion=="/"||ecuacion=="^"){
            Nodo aux1 = stack.desapilar();
            Nodo aux2 = stack.desapilar();
            Nodo total = new Nodo(ecuacion,aux2, aux1);
            System.out.println("hole");
            stack.apilar(total);

        }
        else if (ecuacion=="&"||ecuacion=="~"){
            Nodo aux1 =stack.desapilar();
            Nodo total2 = new Nodo(ecuacion,aux1);
            System.out.println("holo");
            stack.apilar(total2);
        }
        else{
            Nodo total3 = new Nodo(ecuacion);
            System.out.print("hele");
            stack.apilar(total3);
        }


}
```

My problem is that it's not detecting if it's a binary operation or not. It goes to the else immediately. I print the Hole, holo and hele to see where the elements are going, but all I get is hele.

```
 x
 hele4
 hele^
 helex
 hele3
 hele+
 hele*
```

I really don't know why it's skipping the other Ifs, if it's a binary operation or unary.
Just in case, here's the Tree class

```
public class Nodo{
  Object element;
  Nodo izq;
  Nodo der;
  Nodo(String x, Nodo y, Nodo z){
     element = x;
     izq = y;
     der = z;
  }
  Nodo(String x, Nodo y){
     element = x;
     izq = y;
     der = null;
  }
  Nodo(String x){
     element = x;
     izq = null;
     der = null;
  }
}
```

And the Stack (supposed to be a stack of Nodes)

```
  class PilaArreglo{
       private Nodo[] arreglo;
       private int tope;
       private int MAX_ELEM=100; // max numbers on stack

       public PilaArreglo(){
          arreglo=new Nodo[MAX_ELEM];
           tope=-1; // empty stack
       }

       public void apilar(Nodo x){
            if (tope+1<MAX_ELEM){ // if full, OVERFLOW
               tope++;
               arreglo[tope]=x;
            }
            else{
               MAX_ELEM=MAX_ELEM*2;
               Nodo[] nuevo_arreglo=new Nodo[MAX_ELEM];
               for (int i=0; i<arreglo.length; i++){
                    nuevo_arreglo[i]=arreglo[i];
               }
            tope++;
            nuevo_arreglo[tope]=x;
            arreglo=nuevo_arreglo;
            }
       }
       public Nodo desapilar(){
             if (!estaVacia()){ // si esta vacia se produce UNDERFLOW
               Nodo x=arreglo[tope];
               tope--;
               return x;
              }
              return null;
       }
       public Nodo tope(){
           if (!estaVacia()){ // si esta vacia es un error
              Nodo x=arreglo[tope];
              return x;
           }
           return null;
       }

       public boolean estaVacia(){
           if (tope==-1)
       {
              return true;
       }
           else
       {
              return false;
       }
 }
```

I'll appreciate every help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `==` to compare strings where you should be using `.equals` when detecting operators.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. And I also had to change a lot of stuff for it to work. Appreciated!

Comment: Kyle, you can click the green checkbox to accept my answer